# MySQL - Listing a parents children using the Materialised Path approach

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

As you'll see from the below example, I have a `user` table which has two important columns:

- `ManagerUserId` - the manager of that particular user.
- `Lineage`  - this columns comes from the [Materialised Path](https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/more-trees-hierarchies-in-sql) approach, good read if interested in another way to store hierarchical data in MySQL. Stores the path from the current user to the top most manager.

What I'd like to do is: ***Enter in someone's name and return all of their direct reports (children)***.

We work out someone's direct reports by looking at the `Lineage` column and performing a `LIKE` such as:

```
WHERE Lineage LIKE ('1.2%')
```

This would return all of the elements which has the start of their `Lineage` value starting with `1.2`.

I've been fiddling around with it and have provided my attempt below and I hope this articulates what I'm aiming to do.

---

**In MySQL-8.0:**

> ```
> select version();
> ```
>
> ```
> | version() |
> | :-------- |
> | 8.0.13    |
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE user (
>   `Id` INT primary key, 
>   `Name` VARCHAR(55), 
>   `ManagerUserID` INTEGER, 
>   `Depth` INTEGER, 
>   `Lineage` VARCHAR(255)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO user (
>   `Id`, `Name`, `ManagerUserID`, `Depth`, 
>   `Lineage`
> ) 
> VALUES 
>   ('1', 'User 1', NULL, 0, '1.'), 
>   ('2', 'User 2', '1', 1, '1.2.'), 
>   ('3', 'User 3', '4', 3, '1.2.4.3.'), 
>   ('4', 'User 4', '2', 2, '1.2.4.'), 
>   ('5', 'User 5', '2', 2, '1.2.5.');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * from user;
> ```
>
> ```
> Id | Name   | ManagerUserID | Depth | Lineage 
> -: | :----- | ------------: | ----: | :-------
>  1 | User 1 |          null |     0 | 1.      
>  2 | User 2 |             1 |     1 | 1.2.    
>  3 | User 3 |             4 |     3 | 1.2.4.3.
>  4 | User 4 |             2 |     2 | 1.2.4.  
>  5 | User 5 |             2 |     2 | 1.2.5.
> ```

> ```
> SELECT u.Id, u.Name, u.ManagerUserId, u.Depth, u.Lineage
> FROM user u
> LEFT JOIN user m ON m.Id = u.ManagerUserId
> WHERE u.Lineage LIKE (m.Lineage + '%') AND m.Name = 'User 2'
> ORDER BY u.Lineage + u.Depth
> ```
>
> ```
> Id | Name | ManagerUserId | Depth | Lineage
> -: | :--- | ------------: | ----: | :------
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=42e98bbf275962ae8f63bdf8984eeb1a)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produced results for children under 'User 2'

```
SELECT u.Id, u.Name, u.ManagerUserId, u.Depth, u.Lineage
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN user m ON m.Id = u.ManagerUserId
WHERE m.Name = 'User 2'
ORDER BY u.Lineage + u.Depth
```

Updated Answer:

```
SELECT u.Id, u.Name, u.ManagerUserId, u.Depth, u.Lineage,m.id, m.Lineage
FROM user u, user m
WHERE m.Id = u.ManagerUserId 
and u.Lineage like concat((select Lineage from user where name='User 2'),"%") 
and u.Lineage!= (select Lineage from user where name='User 2')
ORDER BY concat(u.Lineage , u.Depth)
```

Comment: I tried this out and it returns only one level of children, I need it to return all levels of children - here's an example where I show results for `User 1` to illustrate this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c91f8069282f8e608f4c1624e70c86c.

I was trying to do this in my example by doing `LIKE (m.Lineage + '%')` as that is how I'd work out all the descendent. But I'm not sure where the `WHERE` would go to be able to just enter in the user's name.

Comment: I've update answer with new query. This should solve the problem.